# Why can you chain some JavaScript methods but not others?

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and I would like to know when it is okay to chain JavaScript methods and when not, and what is the reason when you can't....

I'm creating an element and want to assign a class-name and then put some text inside the element. But for some reason you can't chain these methods.
Ideally I would do something like this:

```
var li = document.createElement("li").classList.add("className").innerHTML = "Some string";
```

I kind of understand why you can't chain the final part, because you can't assign twice. But I can't even chain the second method, instead I have to do this:

```
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.classList.add("className");
li.innerHTML = "Some string";
```

Why is that?

Comment: If the later method can be applied on the return type of the first method then you can chain the methods, otherwise not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chaining isn't anything special. It's just using the return value of a function. If a function returns an object that has a method on it, then you can use that method by calling it directly on the result of calling the function. That is,

```
foo().bar();
```

...works if `foo` returns an object that has a method called `bar`.

You can't do what you've shown in your first code block because:

- `add` doesn't return anything, so the result of calling it is `undefined`.
- If `add` *did* return something, it almost certainly wouldn't be the element `createElement` created. (It probably should return a reference to the `DOMTokenList` you called it on, but it doesn't.)
- And even if it did, the result of an assignment operation (`innerHTML = ...`) is the value that was assigned, not a reference to the element.

---

Side note: If you like chaining APIs, look at using jQuery. It lets you do this:

```
var li = $("<li>").addClass("className").html("Some string");
```

...because most of its API methods return the jQuery instance that they were called on or another useful jQuery instance if not (and `$()` returns the set containing the single element outermost element it creates in the `$("<li>")` example). The API is specifically designed with chaining in mind. The DOM API is not.

Comment: Thanks, for me it was a black box which produced a result but I had no idea what was going on inside the box, thanks for the peek in the box....there is probably a mdn page on chaining I should have checked...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the *return* value of the function. In your case the `li.classList` is an attribute, not a function returning the method itself. Thus you cannot chain it.

Answer (score 2):

Chaining depends on return type of called function

```
document.createElement("li")
```

will return a HTML element which has property called `classList`

`.classList` will return a DOMTokenList. This in turn has property `.add`. But `.add` does not return anything. Hence you cannot call `.innerHTML`

```
document.createElement("li").classList.add("className").innerHTML = "Some string";
```

#### Sample

```js
var element = document.createElement("li");
console.log(element)

var classList = element.classList
console.log(classList)

var add = classList.add('dummy');
console.log(add)
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to use chaining the last method must return a value. If you want to create an instance of an object, every method must return the **this** object.

```
var Dog= function() {
  this.name = 'Buck';
  this.color = 'brown';
};

Dog.prototype.setName = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
  return this;
};

Dog.prototype.setColor = function(color) {
  this.color = color;
  return this;
};
```

So with chaining it will look like this

```
new Dog()
  .setName('Bob')
  .setColor('black')
```

Answer (score 1):

`li.classList.add("className");` this line doesn't return an object (a result of  `li.classList` or simply `li` for instance), instead it returns `undefined` as per this doc: http://www.javascripture.com/DOMTokenList . Thus, you cannot call any methods on the result.